# No audio in Overwatch for Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one, overwatch

When I launched Overwatch there was no sound. I couldn't hear Winston's speech or any other audio in game. When I was in another game just before that I had audio, when I launched another game I had audio, and on the xbox menus I have audio. All of my sound settings are set to 100 and I even tried resetting them to default. I went into the xbox sound settings and nothing there really effected the sound levels. Did I accidentally do something or is it a glitch with the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to the Xbox One's standby mode. Putting the console on standby with Overwatch running often causes this issue.

**Force quitting and restarting the game seems to fix the issue.** You haven't messed up with any of the settings, don't worry - just a buggy game (I had that issue once on PC too).

Try to restart the game and then the console itself if the issue isn't fixed.

Comment: Don't know how hitting restart was any different than turning it off and back on but it worked.